# Apply transformation using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to apply transformation for the list item on mouse click.I want to scroll he list in smoothly using animation.I want to animate with transformation

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $('.flex-next').click(function(){
  $('.thumbnailIcon').each(function(index, item){
   var fourthLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(4)");
    var secondLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(2)");
  $(secondLi).before(fourthLi).animate();
  });

 });
$('.flex-prev').click(function(){
  $('.thumbnailIcon').each(function(index, item){
    var fourthLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(2)");
    var secondLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(4)");
   $(secondLi).after(fourthLi);
  });

 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="parent flex-active-slider">
<div class="node_id"><span>233</span></div>
<ul class="thumbnailIcon">
  <li>left 0</li>  
  <li class="69"> 1</li>
  <li class="233">2</li>
  <li class="299"> 3</li>
  <li>right 4</li>  
</ul> 
</li>
<li class="parent">
<div class="node_id"><span>2</span></div>
<ul class="thumbnailIcon">
  <li>left 0</li>  
  <li class="69">1</li>
  <li class="233">2</li>
  <li class="299">3</li>
  <li>right 4</li>  
</ul> 
</li>
<a  class="flex-prev">prev<a>
<a  class="flex-next">next<a>
```

Comment: Looks alot like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42413649/animate-the-list-using-jquery-function

Comment: see this fiddle. it may help: http://jsfiddle.net/ZXYZ3/139/